# How can I prevent scripts from loading in certain regions across the globe?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to deploy my site in mainland China. The "Great Firewall of China" throttles and blocks requests made to particular hosts e.g. Google Audience tools and Facebook SDK. Due to this, load times on my site are exacerbated -- certain scripts can block the rest of my page from loading for up to two minutes. I would like to effectively comment out these scripts as well as the usage of any variables they inject into the global scope of my app.

Is this an appropriate approach, and if so, how can this be done?

An idea I have is to leverage a tool like freegeojsonip to get the client's ip address and location. If the user is located in China, prevent blocking scripts from loading.

Comment: What code are you using? You'd be best off commenting out the scripts on the server side.

Comment: Another option is to put the <script> tags at the end of the <body> instead of the <head>; this way if they fail to load, the rest of the page would have been loaded and rendered already and wouldn't be dependent on the script loading. You could also try to dynamically load in the files and cancel the request if the request hasn't returned in say, 5 seconds.

Comment: @ACOMIT001, great point -- I can check out the client's request headers, specifically look for the accept-language header, and then if set to "zh" (Chinese), return the index page without scripts.

Comment: but that way youd exclude people from hongkong and taiwan from using the facebook integrated service. id also just comment out the scripts from the server side and just check if the request is coming from mainland china, and if so, deliver the website without the libraries. this way you can still load the facebook apis for chinese people outside of china. also check this http://userinfo.io